# How to get files which are created one hour ago in solaris 5.9

Tags: find, solaris

I want to get files which are created one hour ago, i tried following command

/usr/bin/find /home/FILES/ -name '*.xml'  -atime +.0417 -exec ls -l{} \;

In the above command .0417 is (1 day /24 hours ).

The find command which i am using does not have -mmin option.

Is there a way to  get files created less one hour ago.

Comment: First touch a file with a date of 1 hour old and than use -newer option.
No time to make this a complete answer, so only a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## set the file time to 1 hours ago

```
touch -t 201410042236 /tmp/hourold.tmp;
/usr/bin/find /home/FILES/ -name '*.xml' /tmp/hourold -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```